# Understanding pagefile.sys % Usage performance monitor (perfmon) counter correctly

Tags: memory, performance, perfmon, performance-tuning

Lately we run into performance inssues and I started tracking some recommended sql, memory, disk and cpu counters. I informed myself about the recommended values and numbers to look at.
One of the counters is :

**pagefile.sys % Usage**

We had really small values like 0,5 in the beginning of collecting metrics. When it came to performance problems we reached numbers like `83,69`

Does that mean 83,69% was swapped from memory to disk from the available page file? I am kind of new to this and would love to understand what's going on in order to prevent.

Comment: Can you post the server specification (open a `cmd` -> type in `systeminfo`) as wel as `select @@version` and `max memory setting` for the sql server ? Ideally on a SQL Server, the page file is not used as you dont want Windows to use the swap file for memory. I suspect that your server will need more memory.

Comment: Also read up [The Windows Page File and SQL Server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2010/06/29/the-windows-page-file-and-sql-server.aspx) by BuckWoody

Comment: thank you very much. I will check everything. I think we have set it to 44gb out of 49 but I come back later with more information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pagefile.sys % Usage shows total system committed not what currently is utilized. This value can increase due to load when system finds out it has to back process with more page file.
Have a look at below link for detailed explanation

http://blogs.technet.com/b/perfguru/archive/2008/01/08/explanation-of-pagefile-usage-as-reported-in-the-task-manager.aspx

I would like to know what problem you are facing

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/perfguru/explanation-of-pagefile-usage-as-reported-in-the-task-manager linkrot update :)